# Creating a list view of random words with heart icon on each view tile using the flutter documentation. (Please find the problem below)

Tags: flutter, listview, mobile, flutter-layout, icons

Problem: When the heart icon is clicked, it's supposed to change the icon type from an empty heart to a filled-in heart icon.
Also, when the heart icon is clicked it's supposed to show a red colour that isn't showing up either

Please find the relevant code for the specific widget below

_pairList is the list of random English words that is getting rendered,
_saved is a set that would contain the values that were selected by clicking the heart icon

WordPair is a dart library that has been imported that gets random English words.

```
final _pairList = <WordPair>[];


final _saved = <WordPair>{};

  Widget wordListHolder() {
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(26.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index >= _pairList.length) {
          _pairList.addAll(generateWordPairs().take(10)); /*4*/
        }
        final _getword = WordPair.random();
        final alreadySaved = _saved.contains(_getword);

        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text(_getword.asPascalCase),
              trailing: Icon(
                alreadySaved ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,// main concern
                color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null,// main concern
              ),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (alreadySaved == true) {
                    _saved.remove(_getword);
                  } else {
                    _saved.add(_getword);
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
            Divider(),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
final _getword = WordPair.random();
if (index >= _pairList.length) {
          _pairList.add(_getword); 
        }
```

I think you should have the same items in your `_pairList` and `_saved` lists.

Comment: for the if statement I want to generate 10 more random words when I scroll down which is the reason I have this (generateWordPairs().take(10)) however, _saved is a set that should only have the words that were selected by clicking on the heart icon.

I'm following this documentation 
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

Comment: the problem is that you are generating 10 random words, it ok until you store their data in your `_saved` list. but instead, you are generating a new word (that is also random), so the generated words neve would be in your selected list.

Comment: I see what you mean, also is there a way to console.log the list. I tried  print(), log() but nothing works for some reason. Any suggestions?

Comment: in flutter, you should use `print("YOUR TEXT")` for the logging procedure. Be sure that you have provided a valid `String` value, personally, I usually add a prefix to my string. e.g. `print("MY LOG" + YourVariable.toString())`